# Why am I getting a 'Type Observable<{}> is not assignable to type ‘Observable<object[ ]>’ error?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am writing an application for a grocery list with Ionic, and I’m currently trying to integrate the information in mongoDB with my Ionic app.

However, when I run `ionic serve`, the only thing that loads in the browser is `Cannot GET /`. I’m not sure where I’ve gone wrong in my code.

When I compile, I get the error

> Type `Observable<{}>` is not assignable to type `Observable<object[ ]>`.

I think the problem is in the `getItems` function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
getItems(): Observable<object[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/api/groceries').pipe(
    map(this.extractData),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: What will that api call gonna return ? an object or an array ?

Comment: Because your trying to assign object into array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the type of `this.extractData` is the same as your return function `getItems(): Observable<object[]>` .
meaning if you'll get an Array of Objects from that api call then you need to have them both as `: Array<{}>`.

And for best practices you can create an interface for your data type add it as your observable and variable type like this:

```
export interface CustomData {
        COUNT: number;
        NAME: string;
}
```

Your variable as :
`public extractData: CustomData;`

And your function's return as:
`getItems(): Observable<CustomData> {`

And if you don't wanna do any of that you can just change your function's type to `any` like so: `getItems(): Observable<any> {`